# invisible: True/False parameter exist or not in odoo 8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I am new to odoo.

I searched too many blogs. In openerp 7, it has an optional parameter

```
invisible: True/False

For ex: password = fields.selection([('one','One'),('two','Two')], 'Password', invisible=True)
```

to hide or show the field in view. Whether still it exists in odoo 8.

**UPDATE:**

Also I need to clarify existence of domain filter in Odoo 8.

```
For ex: ... domain="[('fiscalyear_id','=',fiscalyear)]",required=False)
```

Need your help to clarify on this. Or else anyother parameter used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invisible` is still existing in version 8. Try to write in any XML view:

```
<field name="your_field" invisible="1"/>
```

For example:

```
<field name="password" invisible="1"/>
```

Besides, you can make a field invisible depending on a condition, as you were able to do in version 7, with `attrs`:

```
<field name="your_field" attrs="{'invisible': domain_you_want}"/>
```

Where *domain_you_want* is for example `[('another_field', '=', False)]`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have a doubt in model.py file, when declaring object fields.. there is any option to include this parameters (i.e) domain filter and invisible parameter in odoo 8 like openerp 7. Because I am new to this.. Please omit this, if I asked  a wrong question.

Comment: You can use domain in Python code, as you were able to do in version 7, for example `domain=[('your_field', '=', True)]`. But you should use `invisible` only in the XML code, otherwise it's not going to work properly.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to set the answer as correct if it has helped you.