# Hide field odoo in python onchange method

Tags: python, odoo

I have a small question, just to research.
I can hide a field based on attrs in odoo 8, but is there a way to do the same in python code. below is the code:

```
<field name="test" attrs="{'invisible':[('role', '=', 'testrole')]}" />
```

so this does the work ( means hides the field if field name role has value 'test role' )
Then i tried to achieve same functionality using python with method onchange on role field as below:

```
<field name="role" on_change="hide(role)"/>
```

in my model :

```
def hide(self,cr,uid,ids,role) :
    res = {'value':{}}
    if role == 'testrole':
       res['value']['test']['attrs']['invisible']=True
    return res
```

But this does not work, 
Any suggestions ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the way with a second field, too, but i would choose a computed field instead, like:

```py
role = # your role field definition
hide = field.Boolean(string='Hide', compute="_compute_hide")

@api.depends('role')
def _compute_hide(self):
    # simple logic, but you can do much more here
    if self.role == 'testrole':
         self.hide = True
    else:
         self.hide = False
```

Now you can use `attrs` as mentioned by yourself on every other field in that view:

```xml
<field name="fieldToHide" attrs="{'invisible':[('hide', '=', True)]}" />
```

Comment: Thanks CZoellner, I got that I will be needing a field in database. That can only be the solution.

Comment: Actually this solution will work without a field in database. `hide` is computed, but never stored in database.

Comment: Ohh Thanks CZoellner, I will try this. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can create a new Boolean field and this field default set False and in your "rol" field invisible={'boolean_filed','=', True}
and onchange method also apply and you can apply onchange function the "boolean_field" value set True.

```
bool = field.boolean('Boolean')

_default { 'bool': False }


def hide(self,cr,uid,ids,role) :
    res = {'value':{}}
    if role == 'testrole':
         res['bool']=True
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is in this link. But it's better to use invisible only in the XML code, otherwise it's not going to work properly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532390/invisible-true-false-parameter-exist-or-not-in-odoo-8

Comment: Hi Ahmed, it says about invisible in XML, but i am looking for on change method implementation in Python